# Jasmine with Jasminerice: Outputting Errors to Console

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, backbone.js, coffeescript, jasmine

I'm testing my Backbone.js (on Rails 3.2) app using Jasmine and [Jasminerice](https://github.com/bradphelan/jasminerice).  Works wonderfully, however any JS errors are trapped in Jasmine and displayed in HTML.  This is a bit inconvenient as I then have to copy the line number of each trace, go to the file (using Chrome developer tools), then use the "Go To Line" tool to get to that line.

Is there a way to output JS errors in the console as if I were running the application normally?

Thank you for any help.

EDIT:

Found the solution in [ConsoleReporter](https://github.com/pivotal/jasmine/blob/master/src/console/ConsoleReporter.js).

Answer (score 2):

I have the same setup, and I use the [guard-jasmine](https://github.com/netzpirat/guard-jasmine) gem for getting output to the console. Works beautifully. I was initially hesitant because I associated guard with autotest-type functionality, but you can use it just to run all your js tests.

Comment: Thanks.  Do you mean the rails console?  Running guard doesn't seem to affect whether the errors are output to the Chrome console.

Comment: Oh sorry I meant command line -- as in, get the test results to the command line, which doesn't work with just `rake jasmine` if you're using jasminerice. I guess I misunderstood your question.